# checkbox javascript doesnt work in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check the checkbox status for my web in ASP.Net but I can't get the javascript work:

```html
<li>
  <a id="link" href="/ControlHoras">Control Horas</a>
  <input onchange="favButton()" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="ControlHoras"/>
</li>
```

```js
function favButton() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var id = this.id;           
    alert('checked');
  } else { 
    alert('unchecked');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` in `favButton` will be the window, not the clicked checkbox, as you're using an outdated `onchange` event attribute.

You can improve your code and avoid the issue by attaching your event handler using an unobtrusive event handler, like this:

```js
$('#ControlHoras').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var id = this.id;
    alert('checked');
  } else {
    alert('unchecked');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="link" href="/ControlHoras">Control Horas</a>
    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="ControlHoras" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i also try onclick, i have 25 of those checkbox whit different id's (sory my bad english) i need somethig than give me the check status and his ID

Comment: Put a common `class` attribute on them all and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>
    <a id="link" href="/ControlHoras">Control Horas</a>
    <input onclick="favButton()" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="ControlHoras"/>
</li>
```

Comment: 1) onchange is better for checkboxes and radios as it works for users who browse using the keyboard 2) This won't have any effect on the actual problem, so I have no idea why this is even upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to get the caller/sender is through the `event` argument. In fact Firefox ignores events if they don't have the `event` argument.

```
function favButton(event) {
  if ($(event.currentTarget).is(":checked")) {
    var id = event.currentTarget.id;           
    alert('checked');
  } else { 
    alert('unchecked');
  }
};
```